# AngularJS call a function defined in module from another function within the same module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

Given an AngularJS module, there are two functions defined in it, functionA and functionB. How to call functionA from functionB?

```
app.service('myService', [

    function() {

        module = {

            functionA: function() {   ...   },

            functionB: function() {   

                // call functionA

            }

        }

        return module;
    }
]);
```

Comment: @Jack no that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As the function is under the module scope (module = {) it has to be referred with the scope name i.e.

```
module.functionA
```